# How do I test if 2 canvas images are less than x number of pixels away on JS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a game where npcs are everwhere, and I want to interact with them. So put an Image of an exclamation point above their head, which the math worked out okay for positions. But testing the range between the player and the NPC was my trouble. I will shorten the code down as there are more things than just this, also not including the movement. If the players X or Y is in range of let's say 20 canvas pixels, than show the mark. Otherwise, don't.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

NPCs = [
  {
    "name": "tim",
    "sprite": {
      "up": null, // too lazy for that art
      "down": null, // down too
      "left": "images/tim-left.svg",
      "right": "images/tim-right.svg"
    },
    "x": 50,
    "y" 50,
    "onInteract": function(){}, // i dont wanna recreate it
  }
]

function gameLoop() {
  // once again, no movement code shown
  NPCs.forEach(npc=>{
    const NPCimg = new Image()
    NPCimg = npc.sprite.right
    context.drawImage(NPCimg,npc.x,npc.y,canvas.width/10,canvas.width/10) // small, i know
    if (true/*weird cody statement*/) {
      context.drawImage(/*no one cares*/)
    }
  })
}

setInerval(gameLoop,1000/60) // 60 is a fixed number for now
```

```css
/*Not really any CSS but margin auto*/
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="75"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a standard rectangle collision formula and add whatever distance you want, (20) here.

```
function collision(player, obj) {
  if (
    player.x + player.w + 20 < obj.x ||
    player.x > obj.x + obj.w + 20 ||
    player.y + player.h + 20 < obj.y ||
    player.y > obj.y + obj.h + 20
  ) {
    return;
  }
  //do something or return true
}
```

You can also use Pythagorean Theorem for distance.

```
    function distance(player, npc) {
        //center of rectangle 
        let pX = player.x + player.w/2
        let pY = player.y + player.h/2
        let npcX =  npc.x + npc.w/2
        let npcY = npc.y + npc.h/2

        return Math.hypot(pX - npcX, pY - npcY)
    }
```

Then just call it where you need it

```
    if (distance(player, npc) <= (player.w + npc.w + 20) || distance(player, npc) <= (player.h + npc.h + 20)) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Why Player.Width + npc.width

Comment: Because the measurement is from the center of the rectangle. So without accounting for the width or height it would be 20px from the center, which wouldn’t work. Using Pythagorean Theorem is better for a circle since the distance from the center to the side won’t be the same as the distance from the center to a corner. Depends on how accurate you want to be. The second option will be more accurate.

Comment: Ok i tried it and it worked! Thank you for answering at like 3am.

Comment: How else do you party on a Friday night? Good luck!

Comment: Also please accept as answer if it helped you.